# Why does my uninitialised variable become unassigned again after it has its value set inside of TryParse?

Tags: c#, while-loop, scope, out, tryparse

The variable inputBool is declared outside of a while loop, and then set inside of a while loop when I try to parse userInput to a boolean. Once the while loop is exited though, inputBool becomes undeclared again!

However if I initialize the inputBool variable with a value (EG false) it will get set inside of the while loop and will then stay set to whatever it was assigned to inside of TryParse, even after the while loop is exited.

This is the behavior I want, but why doesn't it work when I don't initialize the variable straight away?

```
        foreach (string question in questions)
        {
            bool isBool = false;
            // inputBool declared here.
            bool inputBool;
            string userInput;

            while (!isBool)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(question);
                userInput = Console.ReadLine();

                // inputBool gets assigned a value here in the TryParse.
                isBool = Boolean.TryParse(userInput, out inputBool);
                if (!isBool) Console.WriteLine("Please respond with 'true' or 'false'.");
            }

            // inputBool is unassigned here!
            answers[askingIndex] = inputBool;
            askingIndex++;
        }
```

Comment: Since the loop will always run at least once, use a `do-while` loop.

Comment: Also, are you asking about `isBool` or `inputBool`?  Your question and your code say two different things...

Comment: Whoops! Fixed now.

Comment: and what version of C# is this?

Comment: I support the answers given early to this question, and am offering a suggestion on variable naming: names like isBool and inputBool make the code increasingly difficult to read/recall their purpose. Consider variable names like boolHasAnswer and boolUserAnswer so that you can easily read what the purpose of the booleans are.

Comment: so we're clear, `boolean` is a value type, and so when you say "InputBool is unassigned here" what you mean to say is that it has `false` value and you expect it to be have been assigned `true` given the input\scenario?

Comment: actually seems there was more on this topic than I understood,  I still see two issues with the question.. the first is that code you provided doesn't reflect logic you're stating : assigning `false` to `inputBool` should not affect the while-loop since is uses `isBool` (you indicated to fixed this, but I don't think you have). it should probably be `while (!inputBool)` for the question to make sense.  the second is the same `inputBool is unassigned here!` sentiment.  How are you observing that? is an error occurring, are incorrect results occurring? please update your question to address both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a flow analysis standpoint, there is no guarantee that the `while` loop will get executed at least once. Of course, you know otherwise because your condition involves a `bool` variable that is initialized to a value of `false`, but the compiler is not smart enough to realize it.

Therefore, if it doesn't execute at least once, `inputBool` will still be unitialized at the end, hence the error.

You need to ensure the variable is initialized in *all* code paths. There are two possible fixes:

1. Change the `while` to a `do...while`. That one is guaranteed to execute at least once, which ensures the variable becomes initialized.
2. Initialize the variable to a sensible default value.

Comment: "the compiler is not smart enough to realize it"  Actually, the language spec doesn't permit a compiler that is smart enough :(

Comment: what are you talking about? `bool inputBool` will initialize to `false`.. there is no such thing as an uninitialized valuetype

Comment: you suggest there is no guarantee that the while loop will get executed at least once, but your reasoning isn't clear on that. (was the code snippet updated after you provided this answer or something?)

Comment: ah.. I see that I was incorrect.. after reviewing [MSDN language spec - local variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables#local-variables) I see that there are scenarios where uninitialized\unassigned valuetype occur (specifically in foreach local variable declaration statements).

Comment: @BrettCaswell Local variables in C# must be initialized with a value before they can be read from. Fields get a default value; local variables do not.

Comment: @BrettCaswell Also, I mentionned _from a flow analysis standpoint_. `while` loops do not always execute, just like `if` statements.

Answer (score 3):

The C# language definite-assignment analysis uses only program structure, not data values.

A closely related problem:

```
bool b = f();
int x;
// (1)
if (b) {
    x = 42;
    // (2)
    Trace.WriteLine(x); // ok
}
// (3)
if (b) {
    // (4)
    Console.WriteLine(x); // error, use of potentially unassigned variable x
}
```

Clearly at (1), x is potentially unassigned (certainly, even).  And at (2), x is definitely assigned.  At (3), x is assigned if and only if b is true... but the compiler doesn't try to keep track of this.  It just says "potentially unassigned".  With a result that at (4) the compiler can't prove that x is definitely assigned, even though you and I can.

When the compiler encounters a while loop, it's possible to skip over the loop.  So anything potentially unassigned before the loop is still potentially unassigned after the loop.  Even if you and I can prove that *your* loop terminates only if the variable is assigned, that's conditioned on the data values, not on the structure, and C# doesn't consider it.

You can recreate the compiler's definite assignment analysis pretty easily by making a flowchart of your code.  At any point where two paths combine, apply boolean AND to the status of the variable.

Comment: `x` will be initialized to `0` because it's an `int` valuetype, there is no error in this code.

Comment: actually, I see where I may be mistaken after reviewing on definite-assignment. Your reference to the concept was helpful, but I don't think example reflects the same scenario.  The behavior you're describing is local variable, but not a representative of `foreach_statement` declarations, which seems to be quite relevant to this unassigned value type and error notion.

Comment: @BrettCaswell: The foreach is totally extraneous to the question, you could take just the block inside the foreach and it would have the same problem.